# CakePHP: Chinese translation error

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, cakephp-2.4

My site has three language: russian, english and chinese. I created .pot files with cake console and changed their extension to .po. Then, I put them in Locale/rus, Locale/eng and Locale/chi. Russian and English translations are working perfectly, but Chinese translation are loading Russian .po instead of its own

Comment: Try clearing the cache (`app/tmp/cache`), double check that the chinese locale files contain the expected data, and shouldn't the 3-letter country code for China be `chn`? (AFAIK `chi` is Chile)

Comment: @ndm I already cleared the cache. Even ran `vagrant destroy; vagrant up`
According to [Cakebook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) `chi` is correct variant for chinese

Comment: Sorry, mixed up country- and language code :)

Comment: @Rulisp : Where can I find `Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese language` .`pot` file. Is there any resource I can download or I have to create my own?

Comment: @urfusion well, you need to run ./Console/cake i18n extract to generate default .pot file (I think that you know about it). It will scan all your files for `__()`. Then, you can use [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) to generate `.po` files you need.

Comment: @Rulisp : Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `chi` is the bibliographic alias, you can use it for `Config.language`, but the folder has to use the terminological name, which is `zho`.

> The terminological codes (first one per language) should be used if possible.
>   They are the ones building the path in `/APP/Locale/[code]/`
>   The bibliographic codes are aliases.

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.7/lib/Cake/I18n/L10n.php#L83-L85

Comment: Renamed `chi` to `zho`. Nothing happened. But I found something else. Cake replaces any language (except English and Russian) on the Russian

Comment: @Rulisp It works fine for me with `zho`. Have you checked whether it's working with a fresh copy of CakePHP? Also maybe you could add some code of your application, where you set the language, where you are translating strings, etc... You could also try to debug [**`I18n::_bindTextDomain()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.7/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php#L301), and check what [**`$localeDef`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.7/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php#L321) contains, maybe this gives you a hint where something goes wrong.

Comment: renamed `chi` to `zho` again. It looks like a problem in my VM, since on server, Chinese translation is working fine.